# Posting login form credentails to server and receving response using backbone in pure html page

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, forms-authentication, requirejs

I am relatively new to backbone. I am simply trying to authenticate user against server.

**Form**

```
<form action="/login" id="login-form">
    <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" >
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" >
    <a id="login">Sign in</a>
</form>
```

This is mobile application client form.

**Clicking login**

Clicking login should post the form credentials, username and password, to restful api expose.

**My Restful service**

My web service is hosted separately. It is accessible as

```
  http://myservice.com/api/auth.
```

When i post

> > ```
> > { "username" : "admin", "password" : "abc" }
> > ```

it returns on if authentication success

> > { "id":1, "username" : "admin", "password" : "abc" }

it returns if authentication fails

> > { "message": "Invalid username or password."}

**My Try**

I created model like this

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore'], function($, Backbone, _){

var AuthModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    },
    url:"http://myservice.com/api/auth"
});

return AuthModel;
});
```

I created View like this:

```
 define([
    'jquery', 
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'models/index-model'], 
  function($, Backbone, _,  AuthModel){
 var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
     model: new AuthModel(),
     el: $("#login-form"),
     events: {
         "click #login": "login"
     },

     login: function(){
         this.model.save({username: this.$el.find("#username"), 
         password: this.$el.find("#password")}, {
             success: function() {
                 alert('success');
             },

             error: function() {
                 alert('fail');
                 /* handle the error code here */
             }
         });
     }
});

return new LoginView();
 });
```

This always alerts fail.

**My assumetion**

I think I may be wrong in two places.
One is I am confused how to connect to service hosted seperately.
we usally set

> > ```
> > url:"api/auth"
> > ```

Now, I am trying to set it as

> > url:"http://myservice.com/api/auth"

I am be wrong here how to set them properly and not getting connected anyway.

Or I think i got wrong around this code while saving model

```
 this.model.save({username: this.$el.find("#username"), 
         password: this.$el.find("#password")}, {
             success: function() {
                 alert('success');
             },

             error: function() {
                 alert('fail');
                 /* handle the error code here */
             }
         });
```

**what I want**

I want to post username and password int the form the api expects i.e. {"username":"something", "password":"something"}. Then, if connection is sucess, i want to go to a.html page, else I want to alert error.

Note: currently I am hosting service at localhost and testing against it.

Comment: Did you allow your host in the myservice.com's crossdomain.xml?

[Wikipedia entry about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: actually when  run in phonegap, it does not matter cross-domain. I dont know how but this was done before too.

Comment: I didn't know this was about PhoneGap. But still in PhoneGap domainwhitelisting is necessary: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: there is no such cordova.xml as document says uner res/xml/cordova.xml, so i to went res/xml/config.xml and set <access origin="*"/> for android. It still doest not  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives error Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON  due to this.$el.find("#username") &&  this.$el.find("#password") if you change them to this.$el.find("#username")[0].value && this.$el.find("#password")[0].value works fine on chrome desktop.

```
// bb.js
$(function () {
    var AuthModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        },
        url: "/api/auth"
    });
    var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: new AuthModel(),
        el: $("#login-form"),
        events: {
            "click #login": "login"
        },

        login: function () {
            console.log('entered');
            this.model.save({
                    username: this.$el.find("#username").val(),
                    password: this.$el.find("#password").val()
                },
                {
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },

                    error: function () {
                        alert('fail');
                        // handle the error code here
                    }
                });
        }
    });
    var loginView = new LoginView();
});

// server.js 
app.post('/api/auth', function(req,res){
    console.log('entered on server');
    res.json({});
});
```

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski, this.$el.find("#username").val() is definately one of mistake i did. Now, I have been able to post correctly. However, I do not get response.May be i need to work on server side now.

Comment: Chech do the requests reach the server, you can use advanced rest client for chrome just to be sure. I don't have much experience  with PhoneGap, but your backbone isn't idiomatic, investing some time in learning the backbone way will pay off a lot. If you're in hurry just goes through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqtYcHyyWJA it's whirlwind of information.